# Sliding Popup in Drupal 6

Tags: 6, javascript

Im trying to create a sliding popup using jQuery in my drupal module .

Referring the code from:

http://karlagius.com/2009/02/08/creating-a-sitepoint-like-sliding-popup-in-jquery/

My popup window, defined in the module, is a html string (using divs, a, img etc) .

How do I pass this html string to .js file. It gets used there in .get(url, function(data)).

Tried using drupal_to_js and drupal_json, both returns the value 0, not the string.
Need some suggestion on how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

You need

1. a [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21core.php/function/hook_menu/6) implementation that will provide you with the url:
2. a page callback funtion that does `print()` or `echo` on the html snippet, then `exit()`. So no `drupal_to_js()` or `drupal_json()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass it using [drupal_add_js](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/6)

Example

```
  // This will add variables in the Drupal.settings object
  drupal_add_js(array('my_module' => array('my_setting' => 'this_value')), 'setting');
```

You can access this variable like `Drupal.settings.my_module.my_setting`